# FOR Command - Moving Files Based On Size and Date (*idiot alert*)

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I've recovered a ton of pictures from a failed hard drive.  The recovery program dumps all the files with a new file name into a folder.  When the folder reaches a certain size, it creates a new folder.  I suspect this is to prevent the problem where thousands of files in a folder make Windows go nuts.  I'm left with numerous folders with hundreds of pictures in each folder.

In order to make a little more sense of it all, I figured out I can sort things by date and size.  The problem is manually moving the files around using Explorer is taking forever.  I would like to get a batch file to do it for me.

Try as I might, I just cannot figure out the FOR command.  You people here on stackoverflow are geniuses far beyond my might.  Please help!

Here are the folder names:

```
recup_dir.1
recup_dir.2
recup_dir.3 and so on...
```

In each folder, I want to have the following folder structure:

```
--Possibly New 
    ----Under .1 Meg
    ----.1 - 1 Meg
    ----1+ Meg
--Probably Already Have
    ----Under .1 Meg
    ----.1 - 1 Meg
    ----1+ Meg
```

**EDIT** The New vs. Already Have is based on file date.  The files with dates from the days of recovery are New.  That means anything from June 6 and newer.  Anything with an older date was probably part of earlier recovery attempts.

So far, there are not many pictures ending up in the .1 meg and higher folders.  I'll eventually dump those all into one folder.  I could even do that with the batch file at this point.

Would anyone be so kind as to help me get this done?

Comment: Some recovery programs are able to recover filenames too - it could be worth retrying the recovery with different software.

Comment: I've already done one recovery that included file names, dates, and the folder structure.  I was missing many files.  The current recovery is getting things that don't include the names.  It has dates for files where it can get it.  The ones with proper dates seem to be the files I recovered with the previous recovery.  The files with new dates are files I didn't get with the first recovery.

Comment: Are any files over two GB in filesize?  Batch math tops out at 2 GB.  Please explain the two sets of target folders too.  How do we know which are which?

Comment: So far, I haven't found anything over 10 megs.

I forgot to add how the new and already have are working out.  New is anything with a date of June 6, 2014 or newer.  Already Have are files that have their original file dates that were created before the drive crashed.  I've edited the original post with this new info about dates.

Comment: `for %a in (*.*) do echo %~ta %~za & pause` <--- paste this in a cmd prompt in one of the folders and report one of the lines using copy and paste, so the date and filesize formats are clear.

Comment: 03/06/2013 12:59 PM 1194764  That date is in the format mm/dd/yyyy.  The file size is in bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is air code (untested) but it might work. It processes folders in `e:\folder` and I took some liberty with the folder names.

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in ("e:\folder\*") do (
   pushd "%%a"
      md new\small new\medium new\large have\small have\medium have\large 2>nul
      for %%b in (*.*) do (
         echo "%%a\%%b"
         for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%c in ("%%~tb") do if %%e%%c%%d GTR 20140605 (set new=1) else (set new=)
         if defined new (
            if %%~zb LEQ 100000 move "%%b" new\small >nul
            if %%~zb GTR 1000000 move "%%b" new\large >nul
            if exist "%%b" move "%%b" new\medium >nul
         ) else (
            if %%~zb LEQ 100000 move "%%b" have\small >nul
            if %%~zb GTR 1000000 move "%%b" have\large >nul
            if exist "%%b" move "%%b" have\medium >nul
         )
      )
   popd
)              
echo done
pause
```

Comment: All I get is
'The syntax of the command is incorrect.'
I took off the @echo off and all the >nul's to see if there was any other output to help diagnose but didn't get any additional help.

Comment: I tested it in an elementary way 21 hours ago, and did change it.  Have you tried copy and pasting the code above again?  Test it on some sample files.

Comment: I had already created a copy of a three folders to play with but they were fairly deep in the folder structure.  I just moved them out to the root of the drive and took out all spaces in the name to see if it would make a difference but I still get the same error.  I shortened up the command to:
`for /d %%a in ("l:\testmove\*") do echo hello`
That also results in:
`The syntax of the command is incorrect.`
Putting the same command directly in the command line (remove one % sign) results in the expected output.  It prints "hello" three times and quits.

Comment: My understanding, however poor it may be, is that you use double %% with variable names when in batch files and single % when directly in the command line.  Yes?  No?

Comment: Are you executing this from the cmd prompt?  It is a batch file.  Are your folders in `L:\testmove` folder?

Comment: I just did some experimenting.  The batch file is located inside the `testfiles` folder.  Originally, I ran the batch file from the command prompt while located in that folder.  This time, I left the batch file where it was but ran it while I was in the root of the drive.  It worked.  Thank you.  I still don't understand why it matters but it works.  It it perfect and awesome.  Thank you again.